# Regarding original IP address

Tags: android, iphone

If A person changes his IP throw a VPN and made an internet call to person B (like whats app call or telegram). How can person B get his original IP... any specific method or app for this.

Answer (score 0):

If the VPN is working correctly, you can't.  That's the entire point of a VPN.  The traffic looks like its coming from the VPN.